# Split array and read to specific line

Tags: string, vb.net, textbox

I have a self-written newsletter-sending-tool from a co-worker which writes a textfile as log after sending emails like this:

```
Count of emails to send: 10
Count of sent emails: 10
<German> Sender: infotest@test.de Header: New Newsletter 01/2017, file: C:\temp\raw_newsletter_htm_german.htm
1. (30.01.2017 10:28:45) ------ testadress1@test.de
4. (30.01.2017 10:28:46) ------ testadress2@test.de
5. (30.01.2017 10:28:47) ------ testadress3@test.de
9. (30.01.2017 10:28:47) ------ testadress4@test.de
10. (30.01.2017 10:28:47) ------ testadress5@test.de
<English> Sender: infotest@test.de Header: New Newsletter 01/2017, file: C:\temp\raw_newsletter_htm_english.htm
2. (30.01.2017 10:28:46) ------ testadress6@test.de
3. (30.01.2017 10:28:46) ------ testadress7@test.de
6. (30.01.2017 10:28:47) ------ testadress8@test.de
7. (30.01.2017 10:28:47) ------ testadress9@test.de
8. (30.01.2017 10:28:47) ------ testadress10@test.de
```

Now my question: How can I split the log by language and write them to 2 different textboxes? I tried the following, which just checks if the line contains the "------", because these are the only lines I need. But I have no idea, how I can split them by language.

```
Private Sub readlog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles readlog.Click
    Dim text As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\log_01_2017.txt")
    TextBox1.Text = ""

    Dim entries As String = ""
    For Each line In text
        If line.Contains("------") Then
            entries += vbNewLine & line
        End If
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = entries
End Sub
```

I thought about something like `line.contains("<German>")`, then ignore first line because it's the sender/header/file line and read until `line.contains("<English>")` and then start again with english. But I have no real idea how to write this as code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, I've used RichTextBoxes so the results are easier to see. Basically it iterates through each line of the file.

If it finds a line containing "Sender:" then it sets a RichTextBox object to the destination depending on which country is found between the < and > symbols.

If it finds a line containing "------" then that line is added to the destination that was last selected.

That should point you in the  right direction

```
   Dim txt As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\log_01_2017.txt")
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    RichTextBox2.Clear()
    For Each ln As String In txt
        Dim country As String
        Dim entries As String = ""
        Dim destinationTextbox As RichTextBox
        Select Case True
            Case ln.Contains("Sender:")
                country = Split(ln, ">")(0).TrimStart("<")
                If country = "German" Then
                    destinationTextbox = RichTextBox1
                ElseIf country = "English" Then
                    destinationTextbox = RichTextBox2
                End If
            Case ln.Contains("------")
                destinationTextbox.Text = destinationTextbox.Text & ln & vbCrLf
        End Select
```

Comment: For me it doesn't work, because `destinationTextBox` is still `nothing` when `Case ln.Contains("------")` gets called. How can I make the destionationTextBox = the result from the first case and then use it in the second case?

Comment: Maybe I got something wrong yesterday. `destinationTextbox` isn't `nothing`, but whenever I try to get which country is currently selected by just adding `MsgBox(destinationTextbox.ToString())` it just tells me: `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, Text:`, and not the value assigned by the if-clause above. How can i solve this?

Comment: MsgBox(destinationTextbox.ToString()) only shows the default property of `destinationTextBox` which is the `.name` property. You should use MsgBox(destinationTextbox.Text)

Comment: Mistakes were made! I used "Englisch"(which is just the german word for 'english') for the if-clause but my log-file contains 'english'. Works perfect now. Thank you very much!